# JavaScript: Return Rating Value from Array Using Internal Prototype Method within Factory Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, methods, factory

I am trying to create an object from a factory function.  This object contains an internal prototype which consists of different methods.

I am stuck on what to return from the getStars() method.

Internal Prototype:

```
const obj = {

    addStars(rating){
        return this.rating.push(rating)
    },
    getStars(?){
        ??? 
    }
}
```

Factory Function:

```
function createRecipe (ingredients, cooktime, rating='') {

    let instance = Object.create(obj)

        instance.ingredients = ingredients;
        instance.cooktime = cooktime;
        instance.rating = []; 

        return instance 
}
```

Object being created:

```
const recipe1 = createRecipe(['cheese', 'dough', 'basil'], 20)
```

Right now, I can add different people's starRatings into the rating array which is in the object's property.  Like below:

```
recipe1.addStars('*****');
recipe1.addStars('***');
recipe1.addStars('*');
```

My question is I want the getStars method in my internal prototype to take the average of all the star ratings added to the "rating" array.

What I am hoping to see:

```
recipe1.getStars();  // returns 3
```

How do I manipulate the getStars() method to get my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `reduce` to sum all the values, then divide by the length.

```
getStars() {
  let allStars = this.ratings.reduce((a, { length: c }) => a + c, 0);
  let avg = allStars / this.ratings.length;
  return avg;
}
```

Or a one-liner:

```
getStars() {
  return this.ratings.reduce((a, { length: c }) => a + c, 0) / this.ratings.length;
}
```